# D3 charts : How to open a radar ticket by clicking on the graph.?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create a functionality wherein a bar graph is rendered using d3 charts. 
On click of the bars I should be able to open a radar ticket.

This is the code I have tried but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't know if my syntax is wrong. Or if the functionality is not feasible.

```
var barRect = d3.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d,i) { '<a href =<rdar://problem/12345>></a>' });
```

When I use a simple alert message it works.

Please suggest. The radar tickets are usually a hyperlink in this format:

```
<rdar://problem/12345>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onclick function we're executing javascript - not adding html to the page.

```
var barRect = d3.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d,i){
  window.location = 'rdar://problem/12345' });
```